# How to route in Aurelia (Error route not found)

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I made a simple router. However, I needed to divide the main router into two subrouter.
And after that, routing stopped working. I'm getting an error in the console:
**"Error: Route not found: /name"**

**main-router.js**

```
  configureRouter(config, router) {
    this.router = router;
    // config.title = 'Aurelia';

    config.map([
      {
        route: ''
        , name: 'home'
        , moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('./front')
        , nav: true
      }, {
        route: 'dashboard'
        , name: 'dashboard'
        , moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('./dashboard')
      }
    ]);

    this.router = router;
  }
```

**main-route.html**

```
<template>
    <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

*--------This is 1st child router--------*

**front.js**

```
  configureRouter(config, router) {
    this.router = router;
    // config.title = 'Aurelia';

    config.map([
      {
        route: '', name: 'front-home', moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('pages/main-page/app'), nav: true
      }, {
        route: 'contacts', name: 'front-contacts', moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('pages/contacts/contacts'), nav: true
      }, {
        route: 'price', name: 'front-price', moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('pages/price/price'), nav: true
      }
    ]);

    this.router = router;
  }
```

**front.html**

```
<template>
    <require from="../pages/header/header"></require>
    <require from="../pages/footer/app-footer"></require>

    <header></header>
    <router-view swap-order="with"></router-view>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</template>
```

*Here I want to use router in*

**header.html**

```
<template>
    <require from="./header.scss"></require>
    <nav class="top-nav">
        <div class="nav-wrapper grey lighten-5">
            <a href="#" class="brand-logo center grey-text text-darken-3">
                <svg class="header-logo"></svg>
            </a>

            <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a class="grey-text text-darken-3" route-href="route: front-price;">Price</a></li>
                <li><a class="grey-text text-darken-3" click.delegate="navigateToContacts()" >Contacts/About</a></li>
            </ul>
</template>
```

**header.js**

```
import {inject, LogManager} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';

const log = LogManager.getLogger('Header');

@inject(Router)
export class Header {
  constructor(router) {
    this.router = router;
    log.info('ROUTER => ', router);
  };

  navigateToContacts() {
    this.router.navigateToRoute('front-contacts');
  }
}
```

There are two ways which i'm trying to do this.
1st: With inject the route. And after that trying to call 'navigateToRoute'

```
this.router.navigateToRoute('front-contacts');
```

2nd: With custom attribute 'route-href'

```
<li><a class="grey-text text-darken-3" route-href="route: front-price;">Price</a></li>
```

in both of these cases I get an error

Comment: I make it work by some changes in the main-router.js
Instead of ' ' i inserted this 'home'.
 `{ route: 'home', name: 'home', moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('./front'), nav: true }`
But now my browser address bar looks like **'/#/home'** and 
**'/#/home/contacts/'**
There is another way?

Comment: your code looks fine. what you're trying to do here might be better solved by using multiple shells instead of child routes. if you have a running example that might help. try copying your code  here: https://gist.run/?id=694735d4696c7bb371f0c3025af1fe5e

Comment: https://gist.run/?id=a551f0b3d930e843c27593917e58efe4

 I want to make two different pages with two different routes. And I want to use front.js without changes in address bar. example: Only this router should be surrounded by a header and footer. 1st router (front.js) / - main page (front-home) /about - (about) 2nd router (dashboard.js) /dasboard - (dashboard-page) /dasboard/orders etc

Comment: Thank you for help. I found a solution, you can see below.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
If someone wants to use a similar routing, then you need to change the address of the router, which will be the main one.

This is **main-router.js**

```
 configureRouter(config, router) {
    this.router = router;
    // config.title = 'Aurelia';

    config.map([
//      {
//        route: ''
//        , redirect: 'home'
//      }
      {
        route: ['', '*path']
        , name: 'home'
        , moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('./front')
        , nav: true
      }, {
        route: 'dashboard'
        , name: 'dashboard'
        , moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('./dashboard')
      }
    ]);

    this.router = router;
  }
```

He has two child routers
 1. **front.js**
 2. **dashboard.js**

thanks to this line you can use next routing

```
route: ['', '*path']
```

**front.js**

- /contacts
- /about

**dashboard.js**

- /dashboard
- /dashboard/order

etc..